PM2 + Node.js + Ubuntu: Garbage collection does not work as expected
Edit 09.24: I found the culprit. I was cause by the usage of useAsyncData inside a pinia (setup) stores. Don't do that ⚠️
Original message:
We are having problems with our Production Nuxt3 app. It runs on PM2 (cluster mode) on an ubuntu VPS. The memory usage keeps growing over time.
When run locally (Node and PM2 installed on Windows or Mac), a stress test does fill the memory, but eventually the garbage collection seems to do its job:
PM2 monit, seconds after the stress test and one hour after the test:

When running on ubuntu, the memoy usage stays up.
PM2 monit (production server, Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, node v20.14.0, PM2 5.4.0) after 17 hours of uptime:

As a result, we have to restart PM2 every couple of days.
I tried using --optimize_for_size for Node. This reduced the overall memory usage, but not the growth.
I reproduced this behaviour on my Windows PC with WSL. After the stress test the memory usage stayed high. So the culprit must have something to do with Ubuntu. Any ideas? 

It could be possible that you have a memory leak somewhere in your application. Check if you are not doing things that cannot be garbage collected on the server-side, like wrongly using plugins (see second article), creating intervals that are not cleaned up, etc.
Here are some articles that could possibly help:

https://medium.com/le-collectionist/solving-server-side-memory-leaks-on-nuxt-js-ecd6b16b54a0
https://medium.com/@oliverolmaru/memory-leak-in-ssr-nuxt-js-if-everything-else-fails-1a28e6c2e360
https://medium.com/@samer.kmd/revealing-memory-leaks-in-frontend-applications-nuxt-js-vue-3614334cc00c


Thanks - I already read all these articles. Still, I am wondering why the garbage collection works on our local machines?

I'm not sure, windows could possibly handle memory allocation differently. Have you got some results from the node inspector on the local ubuntu instance? Maybe that would give some more insight in the problem. Also, have you tried removing certain features / parts of the application to look where the problem could lie?

@Tim very common issue. Might be a server/Node issue, maybe try to narrow it down as said above by removing pieces of the framework. Or even try without the framework whatsoever, which might help narrow it down.

Yeah, we probably have a memory leak somewhere. I just can't find it
